# Fixing gdalwarp bounding box when trying to orthorectify using GCPs

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I'm trying to orthorectify a raw, raster satellite image with a set of ground control points (GCPs) using `gdalwarp`. I first create a temporary tif to add in the GCPs using `gdal_translate`, then I orthorectify it with `gdalwarp`:

```
    gdal_cmd_string = "gdal_translate -co compress=lzw -co BIGTIFF=YES "
    for i in range(lat_lon_np.shape[0]): 
        gdal_cmd_string += f"-gcp {mkpts0_np[i,1]} {mkpts0_np[i,0]} {lat_lon_np_fit[i,1]} {lat_lon_np_fit[i,0]} "

    gdal_cmd_string += f"\"{path}/{tiff_name}\" \"{path}/temp.tif\" "
    os.system(gdal_cmd_string)
    os.system(f'gdalwarp -r bilinear -t_srs EPSG:4283 -tps -overwrite -co COMPRESS=lzw "{path}/temp.tif" "{path}/{corona_mission}.tif"')
```

However, when I run this code, the orthorectified raster ends up getting clipped by the bounding box:
[image: clipped raster image over map in QGIS]

I know that `gdalwarp` has the `-te` option to set extents, but I don't know what those are before I orthorectify using the GCPs. Is there a way to have `gdalwarp` automatically update the bounding box when I orthorectify? Or is there another, better approach?

**EDIT**: here are the literal GCPs in the command:

```
gdal_translate -co compress=lzw -co BIGTIFF=YES -gcp 3603.0 796.0 118.96892658239808 29.61845463406411 -gcp 3375.0 808.0 118.93782048752443 29.61731167367309 -gcp 3605.0 811.0 118.96920600768455 29.61702502280883 -gcp 3474.0 815.0 118.95099791834265 29.61664226684981 -gcp 3503.0 817.0 118.95498624245727 29.616450653510274 -gcp 3575.0 827.0 118.96501186443136 29.61549027613256 -gcp 3483.0 828.0 118.95223116118102 29.615394029779118 -gcp 3534.0 843.0 118.95928792739491 29.613945922353555 -gcp 3383.0 844.0 118.93885250332035 29.61384909379729 -gcp 3547.0 848.0 118.961099972754 29.61346142843741 -gcp 3402.0 880.0 118.94132991641999 29.61034083302208 -gcp 3666.0 890.0 118.97768512597946 29.609359052394126 -gcp 3408.0 904.0 118.94211953490495 29.60797970448477 -gcp 3325.0 912.0 118.93153909822605 29.60718908846771 -gcp 3901.0 912.0 119.00774569832028 29.60718908846771 -gcp 3164.0 923.0 118.91394257606007 29.606099275182878 -gcp 3325.0 939.0 118.93153909822605 29.604508815746705 -gcp 3870.0 943.0 119.0041642373994 29.604110279201034 -gcp 3360.0 949.0 118.93590446822121 29.603511817990253 -gcp 3887.0 952.0 119.00614733363814 29.603212299854693 -gcp 3810.0 954.0 118.99683182231841 29.60301251706397 -gcp 3854.0 958.0 119.00225766797915 29.602612706630207 -gcp 3398.0 962.0 118.94080539207977 29.602212576880067 -gcp 3390.0 967.0 118.93976102629215 29.601711978730993 -gcp 3357.0 977.0 118.93552436317141 29.6007093929379 -gcp 3367.0 986.0 118.93679544615398 29.599805573441888 -gcp 3770.0 995.0 118.99169611029723 29.598900441603874 -gcp 3831.0 998.0 118.99945321680926 29.598598456259488 -gcp 3353.0 1008.0 118.9350192173193 29.597590910291395 -gcp 3847.0 1012.0 119.00141187398572 29.59718751336548 -gcp 3959.0 1024.0 119.01400026573809 29.595976136333466 -gcp 3910.0 1028.0 119.00875590594899 29.595571977184857 -gcp 3544.0 1032.0 118.96068149093986 29.595167648940695 -gcp 3725.0 1033.0 118.98573052516602 29.595066541464416 -gcp 3473.0 1039.0 118.95086116842107 29.594459693446435 -gcp 3452.0 1041.0 118.94800347785743 29.594257336598385 -gcp 3765.0 1046.0 118.9910423025394 29.593751292390806 -gcp 3421.0 1053.0 118.94384153441 29.593042491778935 -gcp 3432.0 1062.0 118.94530984298329 29.592130663640887 -gcp 3528.0 1063.0 118.95845296543263 29.592029317574 -gcp 3292.0 1078.0 118.92757461066327 29.59050849679248 -gcp 3353.0 1091.0 118.9350192173193 29.589189732923494 -gcp 3379.0 1111.0 118.93833564047847 29.58716026958776 -gcp 3342.0 1118.0 118.93364011435206 29.586449955790346 -gcp 3744.0 1118.0 118.98827073338482 29.586449955790346 -gcp 3465.0 1128.0 118.94976927768384 29.585435360936465 -gcp 3361.0 1130.0 118.9360314043633 29.58523247180288 -gcp 3457.0 1137.0 118.94868132670348 29.58452246491605 -gcp 3711.0 1137.0 118.98384116727397 29.58452246491605 -gcp 3691.0 1151.0 118.98111930687222 29.58310309267876 -gcp 3677.0 1161.0 118.97920006645496 29.582089945385476 -gcp 3443.0 1163.0 118.9467877038802 29.581887398877804 -gcp 3437.0 1171.0 118.94598045591226 29.58107752511726 -gcp 3277.0 1185.0 118.92582640634774 29.579661613519246 -gcp 3388.0 1186.0 118.93950093503435 29.579560551286956 -gcp 3402.0 1187.0 118.94132991641999 29.579459499678062 -gcp 3375.0 1189.0 118.93782048752443 29.579257428866956 -gcp 3845.0 1202.0 119.00116895336674 29.577945091557407 -gcp 3654.0 1223.0 118.97602636915263 29.575829848422917 -gcp 3937.0 1225.0 119.01170096774104 29.575628735637235 -gcp 3347.0 1237.0 118.93426512606254 29.574423428239363 -gcp 3242.0 1238.0 118.92189086729707 29.574323096274284 -gcp 3544.0 1243.0 118.96068149093986 29.573821703100396 -gcp 3369.0 1245.0 118.93705103789235 29.573621272771888 -gcp 3289.0 1246.0 118.92722216422581 29.57352108534579 -gcp 3878.0 1271.0 119.00510308260606 29.571022816475114 -gcp 3639.0 1275.0 118.97394533149344 29.570624316397485 -gcp 3843.0 1280.0 119.00092547816725 29.57012669991954 -gcp 3521.0 1283.0 118.957480141833 29.569828407734324 -gcp 3860.0 1283.0 119.00297704902317 29.569828407734324 -gcp 3776.0 1286.0 118.99247740248114 29.569530328251425 -gcp 3823.0 1293.0 118.99846115150383 29.56883565697605 -gcp 3853.0 1298.0 119.00213726621138 29.56834020977084 -gcp 3793.0 1303.0 118.99467068785358 29.56784540370254 -gcp 3806.0 1304.0 118.99632634954216 29.567746520900695 -gcp 3523.0 1311.0 118.95775793906078 29.567055089405265 -gcp 3839.0 1313.0 119.00043688088599 29.566857782039538 -gcp 3624.0 1316.0 118.971857518279 29.566562028756483 -gcp 3829.0 1325.0 118.99920597756103 29.565676298618836 -gcp 3644.0 1326.0 118.97463985136135 29.56557802870511 -gcp 3757.0 1327.0 118.98999121968157 29.56547978819238 -gcp 3506.0 1335.0 118.95540104072028 29.56469493862153 -gcp 3762.0 1354.0 118.99064885570643 29.56283889802099 -gcp 3519.0 1355.0 118.95720247282514 29.562741535191222 -gcp 3626.0 1360.0 118.97213622092605 29.56225522308456 -gcp 3534.0 1366.0 118.95928792739491 29.561672770753923 -gcp 3613.0 1387.0 118.97032317865806 29.559644233888395 -gcp 3698.0 1399.0 118.98207479045891 29.55849243166258 -gcp 3664.0 1417.0 118.97740908530777 29.556775382639177 -gcp 3685.0 1419.0 118.9802980712059 29.556585417236388 -gcp 3703.0 1420.0 118.98275545333642 29.556490497279967 -gcp 3626.0 1422.0 118.97213622092605 29.556300783527696 -gcp 3431.0 1436.0 118.94517595512455 29.5549775823817 -gcp 3575.0 1450.0 118.96501186443136 29.553663035581963 -gcp 3651.0 1455.0 118.97561078901528 29.55319572201708 -gcp 3410.0 1456.0 118.94238347940056 29.55310239887725 -gcp 3394.0 1475.0 118.9402824174643 29.551338311218917 -gcp 3631.0 1518.0 118.972832561195 29.547413163804947 -gcp 3465.0 1537.0 118.94976927768384 29.545710649540876 -gcp 3180.0 1557.0 118.9154719927213 29.543941050294844 -gcp 3454.0 1562.0 118.94827441586048 29.54350238257166 -gcp 3543.0 1574.0 118.9605420361741 29.542455839534338 -gcp 3524.0 1594.0 118.95789688444002 29.540731768130158 -gcp 3803.0 1601.0 118.9959460030881 29.540134463476797 -gcp 3374.0 1613.0 118.93769197040729 29.53911809468181 -gcp 3386.0 1623.0 118.93924125228182 29.53827857930924 -gcp 3703.0 1630.0 118.98275545333642 29.537695030130212 -gcp 3390.0 1661.0 118.93976102629215 29.53515270611418 -gcp 3356.0 1676.0 118.93539789770314 29.533947947466704 -gcp 3291.0 1689.0 118.92745697511086 29.532917701822434 -gcp 3631.0 1692.0 118.972832561195 29.53268181622488 -gcp 3395.0 1711.0 118.9404130139875 29.531204428234894 -gcp 3262.0 1745.0 118.92411433858737 29.528634302045905 "~/input/geotiffs/D3C1216-401220A030_combined.tif" "~/input/geotiffs/temp.tif"
```

Comment: Can you share the source image and the GCPs as plain numbers `pixel line easting northing`?

Comment: The source image is very large (30000w x 2000h) so it may not be feasible to share.  But I've added the GCPs to the above post

Comment: Your ground control points seem to be all within a very small area around `-gcp 3631.0 1692.0`. A a good practice is to have GCPs well distributed and also near the corners. Certainly you cannot trust that georeferencing is good at the large areas with no GCPs especially with thin plate splin.

Comment: I understand (and we're working on code to collect new GCPs), but is there still a way to make sure that the orthorectified raster is not spilling over the bounds?

Comment: I am not quite sure what happens here and the use case is so unrealistic that it is certainly not tested by the GDAL developers. I would crop the satellite image to the extents of the convex hull your GCPs or somewhat larger before warping.